# Adding a loop to "digital root" function in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I've been trying to do a problem on CodeWars and I'm a bit stuck. The goal is to make a "digital_root" function, where you add the digits in an integer together. (eg- 17 = 7 + 1 -> 8) Here's whats worked so far for that:

```
def digital_root(n):
    return sum([int(n) for n in str(n)])
```

However, that only works if `n`'s first addition of digits is less than 10. For example, 89 will give me 17, when I want 8; I know it needs to be looped, whether it's recursive or not, however I can't quite figure it out. My best attempt was something like this:

```
def digital_root(n):
    sum = sum([int(n) for n in str(n)])
    if sum >= 10:
       digital_root(sum)
```

but I get `UnboundLocalError` from line 2, and I haven't been able to solve that without a `TypeError`. (`'int' object is not callable`) Here's another example with a `While Loop`, but with still more `TypeError`s:

```
def digital_root(n):
    while sum([int(n) for n in str(n)]) >= 10:
        continue
```

Comment: don't use `sum` as variable because you ovewrite function `sum()`

Comment: in `while` you have to assign result of `sum()` to variable if you whan  to use again in loop.

Comment: @furas thanks for the tip with the `while loop`! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt was pretty close, but while you recursively call `digital_root(sum)`, you don't do anything with the result. Also, as noted in comments, don't use `sum` as a variable name.

Try this instead:

```
def digital_root(n):
    s = sum([int(n) for n in str(n)])
    if s >= 10:
        return digital_root(s)
    else:
        return s
```

Or with only one `return` statement, updating the variable instead:

```
def digital_root(n):
    s = sum([int(n) for n in str(n)])
    if s >= 10:
        s = digital_root(s)
    return s
```

Or shorter, using a ternary expression:

```
def digital_root(n):
    s = sum([int(n) for n in str(n)])
    return digital_root(s) if s >= 10 else s
```

Answer (score 1):

A `while` loop would work if you assigned the result of `sum()` back to the variable in the body of the loop, and also added a `return` statement to the function:

```
def digital_root(n):
    while n >= 10:
        n = sum([int(n) for n in str(n)])
    return n   

print(digital_root(89))  # 8
```

There's no need to use recursion here, unless you also use memoization.

Comment: I like how you did this with the `while`, thanks your help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `sum` as variable because you overwrite function `sum()`. And you have to use `return`.

```
def digital_root(n):
    result = sum([int(x) for x in str(n)])

    if result >= 10:
       return digital_root(result)
    else:
       return result 

print(digital_root(89))
```

---

In `while` you have to assign sum to variable so you could use it again

```
def digital_root(n):

    while n >= 10:
        n = sum([int(x) for x in str(n)])

    return n

print(digital_root(89))
```